# AWS Can not be login with SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

After changing the owner of .ssh folder from user to root, i cannot login the remote server with ssh. Here is the error message:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/qj/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-193-83-231.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [52.193.83.231] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file gmail.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file gmail.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-52-193-83-231.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EahONyMKzM6Q4tdEBSa9LwyOFI65KB02GesJGuGE9Ss
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-193-83-231.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/qj/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/qj/.ssh/dqj
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: gmail.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It's really my fault to change owner of .ssh folder.
Anyone help me~

Comment: Seems you need to launch a new server and use attached EBS volume (if there's data needed).

Comment: No other soultion？Such as creating a new user from AWS manager system.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to preserve the server, you could try creating an AMI from the machine. Then relaunching from that. AWS will then attempt to put your public key in `authorized_keys` again, and may well fix the permissions issue in doing so.

If not, you can always launch a new server and attach the broken servers EBS volume to the new server to fix the permissions on the folder. Not garunteed to work though if you've got ephemeral storage or a weird file system.

Comment: i tried to preserve the server under creating an AMI from the machine, while i also can not login the ami. Here is the message:
**Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
Connection to ec2-52-192-184-132.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.**

Comment: ...Did you try logging in with ec2-user as the username instead? You should then be able to `sudo` to modify the files in `/root/`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=133054&tstart=0
Here is the answer:

1. Stop the instance
2. Detach the Root Volume
3. Launch another instance(or if you have one already you can skip this step)
4. Attached the Volume in 2 to the new(or already existing other) instance
5. Log in into the instance
6. Mount the Volume
7. Change the folder permissions as appropriate
8. Umount the Volume and detach it
9. Attach it back to the original instace
10. Start the instance and connect

It occurs some problems at step 6 when mounting the Volume to the new instance using the shell `mount xvdf /ebs/ -t ext4`(mkdir /ebs //this folder is a mount point, more details from [Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)). The error message is :

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Since the file system for the Volume is GPT. Fortunately, I got the reason from this post [Problem mounting GPT disk partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126553/problem-mounting-gpt-disk-partition). And the solution is that i need to mount `/dev/xvdf1`, not just `/dev/xvdf`, such as `mount xvdf1 /ebs/ -t ext4`.
Finally, mounting the volume is successful.